# Edits that consist of making a code block should be valid

Tags: discussion

There's a general limitation on the edit - it has to be at least 6 characters. But for some reason, when I change this:

some_code
some_more_code

to this:

```
some_code
some_more_code
```

the edit isn't valid because it didn't count those 8 space characters.
Now that's a problem, because some people post quite a large code snippet without formatting. Such a post begs for an edit, but since this edit would only consist of indenting the whole code, Stack Overflow editing system doesn't allow that.

So I'm forced to make some other changes that barely improve the post just so the majority of the edit would be accepted. Those changes include actually changing the code (placing missing spaces around operators and such) which should be the OP's preference.

How to edit such posts?

Comment: I just added a carriage return as a test to your post and it was accepted on here, not sure if it's a reputation thing? Either way, changing 6 characters on a post really shouldn't be that hard.

Comment: Yes, it's reputation-based. You have full edit privileges, @tanner, so it doesn't apply to you. This applies only to people who are *suggesting* edits that have to be *reviewed* by other users.

Comment: @CodyGray does that happen @ 2k if I remember correctly?

Comment: Yes, 2k gives you full edit privileges.

Comment: On the positive side, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14721352) was a very good edit. Just bad luck someone else with a higher rep beat you to it. (And she did leave the "school assignment" remark, which is not relevant to the question and so could best be deleted.)

Answer (score 6):

> So I'm forced to make some other changes that barely improve the post

I disagree with this.

I have yet to see a post that is perfect aside from the formatting of code blocks. There is no overlap between people who can't figure out how to format their code and didn't bother to read the formatting help, and people who are persnickety about grammar and style, or who choose the best tags, or who optimize the presentation of their question.

In every case I've seen, the "other changes" you are required to make *substantially* improve the post, and as long as you're submitting edits that other users have to spend time reviewing, they should be *substantial* changes. Six characters is not a high bar.